# How to limit the active JMS listeners for a lot queues?

Tags: java, jms

In my case, let's say that there are 50 JMS queues receiving different type of messages.

If I implemented 50 JMS listeners (one for each queue), it is working pretty good.

However, when all the 50 queues had many pending messages there, all my 50 JMS listeners were working at the same time (i.e. there would be 50 JAVA threads were working). This made my server overloaded (if it has very limited RAM resource and easily got out-of-memory).

So I am thinking whether I can limit the number of active listeners. Let's says, limit to only maximum 10 active listeners at a time. Sometimes listener 01 ~10 work on queue 01~10, and sometimes listener 11~20 can work on queue 11~20 etc.

And even there are new messages coming into queue 01~10, listener 01~10 should be able to sleep for a while and let other listeners to work.

How can I achieve this case?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's one listener per queue, so unless you're going to manage listeners being active/inactive, you'll get a running thread each time a message is delivered to the queue.

What you need is a way to manage the scaling, regardless of where the messages are delivered.  Two ideas come to mind:

1) Does the message processing require some memory-intensive resource that could be shared somehow?  For example, database connections are often shared/pooled to avoid creating too many (though the too-many connections is often a server-side issue, maybe there's another resource that you need to share).

2) Using semaphores, limit the number of concurrent threads allowed by having each thread get a permit from the semaphore before starting, returning it at the end (very important!).  Then, if you get a lot of concurrent messages coming in, only n messages are processed concurrently and the other queue up in the listener handler for the message.

3) You could aggregate messages into new queues that have listeners that do the processing.  Listeners for queues 1-10 post the message to newQueue1, queues 11-20 post the message to newQueue2, etc., and then you have listeners working on newQueue1, newQueue2, etc.